# AngularJS ng-repeat, how can I do more custom looping?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I have a set of items that I want to loop through.  I want to create a new row for every 3 items.  So instead of having 1 row for each item I want 1 row for every 3 items.  So the HTML would look something like this...

```
<div class='row'>
  <div>.. item 1 in the list </div>
  <div>.. item 2 in the list </div>
  <div>.. item 3 in the list </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div>.. item 4 in the list </div>
  <div>.. item 5 in the list </div>
  <div>.. item 6 in the list </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to achieve this using ng-repeat because it keeps creating a new div for each item, is there a way that this can be done in AngularJS?

Comment: I'm turning around this one but I don't think it's possible with ng-repeat. At least, I don't see an elegant solution. However, it should be fairly easy to create a directive that works in the same way as ng-repeat (compile + link functions) with modular arithmetic to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I may just format the data in my controller so that it fits this format better, just wanted to see if there was a way to do it with ng-repeat first

Comment: Chunk your array every 3 items, then use 2 `ng-repeat`s :)